# Is it possible to disable download from OpenSSH SFTP Server

Tags: ssh, sftp

Is it possible to setup an upload-only SFTP server using OpenSSH.

From the manpage (man 8 sftp-server) I found the options to blacklist and whitelist `requests`. But when I tried a `get` option in SFTP the logs showed `OPEN` request with `flags READ`.

I know that I can't disable `OPEN` as it is required for writing as well.

Is there an option to disable the `FLAGS` or any other option to disable downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blacklist the `read` request.

---

`get` is not SFTP protocol *request*. That's OpenSSH `sftp` client *command* that internally uses `open`, `read` and `close` *requests*.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much.